# How to group by with rollup modifier in doctrine?

Tags: mysql, doctrine, rollup

How change this sql in doctrine. Group by with [`ROLLUP` modifier](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) isn't supported by doctrine.

```
SELECT `users`.`username`,`owner`.`name`,`property`.`name`,SUM(`expenses`.`price`)
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `owner`ON `users`.`id`=`owner`.`user_id`
INNER JOIN `property`ON `owner`.`id`=`property`.`owner_id`
LEFT JOIN `expenses`ON `property`.`id`=`expenses`.`property_id`
GROUP BY `property`.`id`,`expenses`.`id`with rollup
```

Comment: I have added both the mysql tag and the rollup tag. If a different vendor for rollup was meant, please add the correct tag.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are out of luck:

> Because `WITH ROLLUP` is a `GROUP BY` modifier, it cannot be solved
>   with a custom function. You'll have to use native SQL for this.

as Jasper N. Brouwer pointed out on a [doctrine user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/doctrine-user/EU-0adlxtyc).